# Laravel 5 : How to render bit field

Tags: mysql, laravel, bit

I've using laravel 5.2 and facing following issue with BIT field its woking fine on my local mahine but on server its return as following:

On server:

```
array:12 [
  0 => {
    "cc_size": "4"
    "cc_hide": "\x00"
  }
]
```

On Local:

```
array:12 [
  0 => {
    "cc_size": 4
    "cc_hide": 0
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance ..!

Comment: Thats an UTF char and it could happen for various reason 1. likely on local db the table charset is utf-8 and in production its set to latin. So while saving the data the latin charset will try to create its own representation of these utf-8 chars. 2. The DB connection should be set to utf8. If you use Doctrine then it should set the connection param as `'driverOptions' => array(
  1002=>'SET NAMES utf8'
    )`
3. Last the html page should have meta charset to utf8 `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty char set is same on both of locations.